# Setting conditionals based on other conditionals

Tags: conditionals

I'm trying to set a conditional `\if...` to true or false based on another condition. Something similar to this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\iffirst

\iftrue
  \let\iffirst\iftrue% ... similar to \firsttrue
\else
  \let\iffirst\iffalse% ... similar to \firstfalse
\fi

\begin{document}

\iffirst
  First
\else
  Not first
\fi

\end{document}
```

The output logically should be `First`, since `\iffirst` is set to `\iftrue`. However, it doesn't work. Why not? I thought once the condition is evaluated (`\iftrue` or `\iffalse`), it executes the true/false clause, with `\let<cmdA><cmdB>` being valid.

Instead of `\let\iffirst\iftrue`/`\let\iffirst\iffalse`, one can use `\firsttrue`/`\firstfalse`. However, these both have the same meaning (that is, `\show\firsttrue` reveals `\let\iffirst\iftrue` and similarly `\show\firstfalse` reveals `\let\iffirst\iffalse`). So, why does `\firsttrue`/`\firstfalse` work, but specifying `\let\iffirst\iftrue`/`\let\iffirst\iffalse` explicitly doesn't?

The following workaround also helps but doesn't answer the question:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\firstoftwo}[2]{#1}% Similar to \@firstoftwo
\newcommand{\secondoftwo}[2]{#2}% Similar to \@secondoftwo

\iftrue
  \let\firstsecond\firstoftwo
\else
  \let\firstsecond\secondoftwo
\fi

\begin{document}

\firstsecond{%
  First
}{%
  Not first
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TeX doesn't look at the syntax of your code when skipping `\if..\else..\fi` blocks, so it doesn't know that `\let` should consume two tokens.  This means that in `\let\iffirst\iftrue` (with `\iffirst` being equal to `\iffalse`) you have two `\if` but no `\fi`, so when TeX tries to balance them it doesn't do what you expect. Re-indenting your code based on what TeX sees, it looks like this:

```latex
\iftrue % \if level 1
  \let\iffirst\iftrue
\else % \else level 1
  \let
  \iffirst % \if level 2
    \iffalse % \if level 3
    \fi % \fi level 3
```

which is obviously wrong.  When executing the code, the `\iftrue` (`\if level 1`) is true, so the `\let\iffirst\iftrue` is executed.  Then `\else` is seen, and TeX starts looking for a `\fi level 1`, but here `\iffirst` and `\iffalse` are misinterpreted and two `\fi` are missing.

A good way to work around this when setting the conditional is to first completely evaluate the `\iftrue..\else..\fi` block, and only *then* do `\let\iffirst\if<something>`, then you make sure that neither is interpreted as starting another `\if` level (this is roughly how `expl3` conditionals are implemented, so they can be easily nested without worrying about balancing `\if..\else..\fi`):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newif\iffirst

\makeatletter
\iftrue
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
  \expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi
  {\let\iffirst\iftrue}%
  {\let\iffirst\iffalse}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\iffirst
  First
\else
  Not first
\fi

\end{document}
```

---

This feature, of not looking at the meaning of the code when balancing conditionals, allows the Dirty Tricks with braces presented in Appendix D. Here's an example of an apparently unbalanced code, which actually works correctly (and note that `text` is not printed in bold face):

```latex
{\bfseries
  bold
  \iffalse {\fi }
  text
```